Why is Minitoc not appearing?

Blockquote


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xurl} % For handling long URLs

% Page setup
\geometry{a4paper, margin=2.5cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}
% Fonts and text
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm} % Times New Roman font

% Title and section formatting
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\bfseries\centering\Large}{\thechapter.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\large}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries\normalsize}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-1.5em}{2em}

% Dot leaders in the ToC
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{1.5}
\renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{1}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecdotsep}{1}

% Header and Footer configuration
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}} % Chapter title on the left
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}   % Thin line under the header
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}                % Page number centered at the bottom
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}     % No footer line

% Redefine \chaptermark to display chapter title in the header
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}


%=============== Customizing Chapter Names and Minitoc Inclusion ===============%
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[english]{minitoc} % Required for minitoc
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{1} % Set minitoc depth (adjust as needed)
\renewcommand{\mtcfont}{\small\bfseries} % Customize minitoc font
\renewcommand{\mtcSfont}{\small}         % Customize minitoc section font

\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1.2ex \hfill \kern \z@}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{
    \vspace*{30\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \thickhrulefill\quad 
        \scshape\bfseries\textit{\@chapapp{} \thechapter}  
        \quad \thickhrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \Huge \bfseries #1 \par\nobreak
        \par
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \hrule
        \vskip 20\p@
    }
    \thispagestyle{empty}%

    \newpage
}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{\hbox{%
    \huge\hbox{\textbf{#1}}%
}\par\vskip 1cm}

\makeatother
%=============== End Customization ===============%


\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

% Preliminary pages
\includepdf[pages=-]{00-Page-de-garde.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{sign.pdf}
\include{Dedicace}
\include{Acknowledgements}
\include{Abstract}

% Table of Contents with dot leaders
\dominitoc
\fancyhead{} % Clears the header for the following section
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\listoffigures \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures} \mtcaddchapter 
\listoftables \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures} \mtcaddchapter 
\clearpage
\include{Abrev}
\clearpage

\fancyhead{} % Clears the header for the following section
% Main content
\include{Intro}

\chapter{Test}
\minitoc \newpage
 \section{AAAAAAA}
 WEFWEFWEFWEFWEF



\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}} % Chapter title on the left
\include{chap1}
\include{chap2}
\include{chap3}
\include{chap4}
\include{chap5}

\clearpage
\fancyhead{} % Clears the header for the following section
\include{General}

\clearpage
\include{Bibliography}
\includepdf[pages=-]{back.pdf}
\end{document}


nobody can test your code as it is incomplete and uses local files. Make a proper, complete, small example.

Have you really checked that the minitoc is definitely absent? I see your \def\@makechapterhead#1 definition, which you conclude with the command \newpage. So, the minitoc will appear on the following page as the first element. P.S. Anyway, yes: you have to revise the code and modify it to provide us with a MWE. amongst other things, you have to add the \documentclass{} command, the argument of which I think is book, but only you can know for certain. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/236280; see also https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/info/dickimaw/dickimaw-minexample.pdf
